# How to avoid duplicate input to my text file in python

Tags: python, string, file, string-matching

I have input coming from an API, and I have  a .txt file, and Im making entries into the text file. And I want to check and insert it, and doesnt need to input if the value is already existing in the file.

Im trying this but It inserts everytime It runs,

```
with open("path.txt", "r+") as myfile:
    # for lines in myfile.read().split():
    if cam_key not in myfile.readlines():
        myfile.write(key + ",")

        print("value adding ")
   
    else:
       
        print("value added")
```

Please let me knw whats wrong here.
FYI(key is the value coming frm API)

Values from api:
"Axx5RR000221AZ,Axx5RR000221QA"

New value:
Axx5R000221SS

It is getting added like this everytime new value comes:
Axx5RR000221AZ,Axx5RR000221QA,Axx5RR000221AZ,Axx5RR000221QA, Axx5R000221SS

As u can see, its replicating when with existing + new values

Comment: readlines() returns an array so you may match exactly a value in the array, and all values ends with a `\n` so do `cam_key+'\n'` or use `.read()` to get one string only

Comment: You are adding a ',' too to the file. you need to check if ```key + "," in file.readlines()``` not
 ``` key in file.readlines()```

Comment: Thanks @KarthikRadhakrishnan Your response worked !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open("path.txt", "r+") as myfile:
    if cam_key not in myfile.read().split(","):
        myfile.write(key + ",")
        print("value adding ")
    else:
        print("value added")
```

Comment: Hi @John Ison, I tried this, but still its adding again and again. I need to input values coming from that api seperated with ",", but then when Im checking I guess its not able to check the string.

Comment: Hi @John, Thanks for your response,  I checked now, keeping if cam_key + ',' in myfile .as suggested by karthik comment worked, I had to check the "," too..